# Installing Less in Ruby - Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-rails, therubyracer

I'm on Windows and i'm Trying to install The [`Flat UI Pro`](https://github.com/reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails) which need's [`Twitter Bootstrap Rails 3.1`](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).

But whenever i try to install [`The Less Stylesheets`](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#installing-the-less-stylesheets), i'm getting a lot of weird errors about `therubyracer` gem an the `V8` file.

I need to run

```
rails generate bootstrap:install less
```

which gives me the error

```
[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- v8    (LoadError)
```

The server doesn't start also

**My Gem File**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'less-rails'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', :platform => :ruby
end
```

If someone has experience or has installed [Twitter Bootstrap for Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) before please give me a helping hand :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can not install twitter-Bootstrap with less file on Window machine because , Window does not support twitter-bootstrap-less library l.e ( libV8 , exec.js , python , error) that not work on Window . 
if you want to run your project on window machine  than used "Bootstrap gem" instead of 'twitter-bootstrap-rails gem' . 
 Otherwise used the Ubuntu OS it is best suited for any Ruby on Rails Application with solve dependency of your GemFile easily . and you used "less-rails", and "twitter-bootstrap-rails" easily  and not come any issue with libV8.